# How to use while loop in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and trying to do a while loop operation with a condition. So please someone provide solution for the below query.

Query: I am trying to do DELETE request for 50 times using the id as reference. So I kept the condition as "${startId}<=${endId}" in the while loop. But the while loop is executing infinitely. Is there any simple mechanism to iterate the loop for 50 times by increment the startId till it reaches endId.

Answer (score 1):

While Controller accepts [function or variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions). So you need to either:

- provide a variable which has value of "true" and becomes "false" somewhere else
- provide a function which returns "false" to exit from While loop.

With your condition it won't evaluate your expression hence it will never become "false". The solution is to wrap your statement into i.e. [__javaScript](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function as:

```
${__javaScript(${startId}<=${endId},)}
```

For more information on JMeter functions see [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series.

Answer (score -1):

You may take help of loop controller and pre-processor.

snaps :
[image]